# Angular URL short domain

Tags: url, url-routing, short, angular-pipe

how can i keep only the domain name in the url browser, example  :https://stackoverflow.com/ThunderRoid → stackoverflow.com
I create a short-domain.pipe, Can i use pipe with routing application? can someone help me please,I am blocked

```
@Pipe({
      name: 'shortDomain'
    })
    export class shortDomain implements PipeTransform {
      transform(url: string, args?: any): any {
        if (url) {
          if (url.length > 3) {
            let result;
            let match;
            if (match = url.match(/^(?:https?:\/\/)?(?:www\.)?([^:\/\n?=]+)/im)) {
              result = match[1];
              if (match = result.match(/^[^.]+\.(.+\..+)$/))
                result = match[1];
            }
            return result;
          }
          return url;
        }
        return url;
      }
    }
```

Comment: What did you try so far?

Comment: I followed the tutorial below the link : https://medium.com/@thunderroid/angular-short-domain-pipe-url-to-domain-google-com-youtube-com-4855706dc4f8       
and I created a pipe (shortDomain) but I can't understand how to use it with the routing of my application

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From your example:

```
<a [href]="dog.source">{{dog.source}}</a>
```

to

```
<a [href]="dog.source">{{dog.source | shortDomain}}</a>
```

Keep the `href` in the `a` Tag the same just add the pipe to the interpolation (`{{  }}`)